# Как выбрать всю строку с максимальным значением в одном столбце для каждой группы?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by, обработка-данных

Имеется общий `df` приблизительно следующего вида:

```
df  po oh io yh qw er ty yu io
id  09 09 87 89 12 23 34 45 1
id  09 09 87 89 12 23 34    2
id  09 09 87 89 12 23 35    3
id  09 09 87 89 12 23 36    4
ids ui jk uj yh 34 56 42 45 15
ids ui jk uj yh 34 56 42    12
ids ui jk uj yh 34 56 43    13
ids ui jk uj yh 34 56 44    14
```

Как корректно сгруппировать с выборкой строки по максимальному значению `io` приведя к следующему виду:

```
 io yh qw er yu io
 87 89 12 23    4
 uj yh 34 56 45 15
```

Или "схлопнуть" основную таблицу, т.е. сгруппировать по столбцу `df` и также вывести строки с максимальным `io`:

```
df  po oh io yh qw er ty yu io
id  09 09 87 89 12 23 36    4
ids ui jk uj yh 34 56 42 45 15
```

Один способов, которые встретил, это `idxmax`. На сколько корректно, в данном случае, при помощи его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример:

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
    df  po  oh io1  yh  qw  er  ty    yu  io2
0   id  09  09  87  89  12  23  34  45.0    1
1   id  09  09  87  89  12  23  34   NaN    2
2   id  09  09  87  89  12  23  35   NaN    3
3   id  09  09  87  89  12  23  36   NaN    4
4  ids  ui  jk  uj  yh  34  56  42  45.0   15
5  ids  ui  jk  uj  yh  34  56  42   NaN   12
6  ids  ui  jk  uj  yh  34  56  43   NaN   13
7  ids  ui  jk  uj  yh  34  56  44   NaN   14

In [62]: res = (df
                .groupby("df", as_index=False, group_keys=False)
                .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, "io2")))

In [63]: res
Out[63]:
    df  po  oh io1  yh  qw  er  ty    yu  io2
3   id  09  09  87  89  12  23  36   NaN    4
4  ids  ui  jk  uj  yh  34  56  42  45.0   15
```